# Bottle + AngularJS - CORS refuses to work

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, bottle

```
Code:

@route('/characteristicsToBestWeb', method='OPTIONS')
def respondToCharToBestQueryWebOptions():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = settings.allowed_web_origin
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    # response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept,' \
                                                       ' Content-Type,' \
                                                       ' Cache-Control,' \
                                                       ' Pragma,' \
                                                       ' X-Requested-With,' \
                                                       ' X-CSRF-Token'

@route('/characteristicsToBestWeb', method='POST')
def respondToCharToBestWebQuery():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = settings.allowed_web_origin
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    # response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept,' \
                                                       ' Content-Type,' \
                                                       ' Cache-Control,' \
                                                       ' Pragma,' \
                                                       ' X-Requested-With,' \
                                                       ' X-CSRF-Token'
    render_response()
```

As you can see, I specify the origin explicitly, and yet I get the following error in the console, using both vanilla `$http` service and `Restangular`.

on the post request:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vitamiter.com/characteristicsToBestWeb. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.vitapersonal.com:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Although the OPTIONS request returns just fine.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Works just fine with XMLHttpRequest:

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", API_ROOT + 'characteristicsToBest?cacheBuster=' + Math.random().toFixed(5) , true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
    req.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    req.onload = function(){
        var response = this.response;
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log(response)
        })
    }
    req.send(JSON.stringify(reqData));
```

WT*-angular?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual headers that get returned?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'
```